# Is it possible to interpolate freemarker macros?

Tags: template-engine, freemarker, templating, string-interpolation, templating-engine

Say I have a freemarker macro:

```
<#macro helloObject>
  World
</#macro>
```

I can call it easily in some contexts:

```
Hello, <@helloObject/>!
```

But what is the syntax for interpolating it, for example, if it's part of a string?

```
<#assign greeting="Hello, <@helloObject>!"     /> <#-- doesn't work -->
<#assign greeting="Hello, ${helloObject}!"     /> <#-- doesn't work -->
<#assign greeting="Hello, ${@helloObject}!"    /> <#-- doesn't work -->
<#assign greeting="Hello, ${<@helloObject/>}!" /> <#-- doesn't work -->
<#assign greeting="Hello, @helloObject!"       /> <#-- doesn't work -->
${greeting}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can.

```
<#macro helloObject>
  World
</#macro>

<#assign x><@helloObject/></#assign>

Hello ${x}.
```

Will print:

```
Hello World.
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a [function](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_function.html).

```
<#function helloObject>
  <#return "World">
</#function>

${helloObject()} <#-- Will print out World -->    

<#assign greetings = "Hello, " + helloObject() />

${greetings} <#-- Will print out Hello, World -->
```

The result of a macro cannot be assigned, because it is a template fragment.

Comment: The reason the result of a macro can't be (easily) assigned is that it's like function VS procedure in some languages; macros meant to be called for their side-effects (one of them is printing to the output stream). But actually one can assign the captured output of a macro to a variable, but it's bad practice because it's easy to mess up auto-escaping then (`<@...>` is never escaped as it meant to output markup, but `${someCapturedOutput}` is subject to auto-escaping).

Comment: So I'm in a bit of a dilemma here then. On the one hand, I'd think I want to use a macro, since the macro will mostly be outputting HTML (maybe a little freemarker interpolation in there too). But on the other hand, it makes it simpler to use a function. Which is worse--using a function to write something called only for its side-effect, or assigning the output of a macro to a variable?